# how to make a popover overflow: visible inside overflow: auto context

Tags: html, css, position, overflow

I have a list of divs (overflow-x should scroll if the parent box is exceeded), and on hover, I want to see a popover.

My problem is, that if I hover any child div, the popover is considered for the overflow calculation, but I just want to have it visible on top of everything and not make it extend the scrolling area nor have it hidden on the right border of the parent. Can I detach it from the parent/child context somehow?

`.parent {overflow-x: visible}` is not an option, since I want to keep the parent size and have the children scrollable.

```css
div {
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 10px;
}

.parent {
  overflow-x: auto;
  
  white-space : nowrap;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.popover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  
  z-index:9999;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.child:hover .popover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="popover">
    </div>
  </div
  ><div class="child">
    <div class="popover">
    </div>
  </div
  ><div class="child">
    <div class="popover">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO there is no way around the behavior you're trying to avoid with plain HTML / CSS, as long as your popup lives inside a div with "overflow: auto", "overflow: scroll" or "overflow: hidden". But please put me right somebody.

I would suggest using minimal JS (jQuery) for that, as per my example. It can be done using vanilla JS as well, but IMHO it's not worth the effort.
Basically the JS does three things, (1) attaching to the mouseenter and mouseleave events, (2) stopping the event's further propagation of the in the capturing and bubbling phases, and (3) setting the position of the popup.

This has the additional benefit of being able to control various other aspects of you popup as well.

Just for the sake of completeness, I created a plain vanilla JS version as well, although I would not go that way.

https://jsfiddle.net/rq1xc548/

```js
$(".child").on( {
    mouseenter: function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        let position = $(this).offset();
        $(this).find(".popover").css("top", position.top);
        $(this).find(".popover").css("left", position.left-10);
        $(this).find(".popover").css("display", "block");
    },
    mouseleave: function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find(".popover").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

```css
div {
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 10px;
}

.parent {
  overflow-x: auto;
  
  white-space : nowrap;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.popover {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  
  z-index:9999;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="popover">
    </div>
  </div
  ><div class="child">
    <div class="popover">
    </div>
  </div
  ><div class="child">
    <div class="popover">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```