# position absolute element is not reliably removed from the document flow

Tags: html, css, position, overflow

According to the documentation, `position: absolute` elements are removed from the flow and do not affect other elements on the page.

[mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
> created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative
> to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed
> relative to the initial containing block.

But as soon as I place it inside a `position: relative; overflow-x: auto` element, the absolute child is considered by its ancestor and is affecting the overflow behavior of the relative element. How can I make the overflow auto parent ignore the absolute element and make it look like the other examples? it needs to be relative and absolute so it behaves correctly in the overflow parent ([how to make a popover overflow: visible inside overflow: auto context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71160816/4126424)).

A relative parent is often recommended for absolute elements, so it is a pretty common use case, and I am confused If I misunderstood something here.

```css
div {
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 5px;
}

.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.overflow-auto {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child absolute">
    parent static (default)
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent relative">
  <div class="child absolute">
    parent relative
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent overflow-auto">
  <div class="child absolute">
    parent static overflow-auto
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent relative overflow-auto">
  <div class="child absolute">
    parent relative overflow-auto
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand what you're talking about just from your description, maybe some images of what you're expecting would be helpful to help people answer.

Comment: Just remove `overflow-x: auto`, Not sure why this is being applied in the first place.

Comment: I need overflow auto for other reasons, I just reduced it to the minimum to explain the problem. The problem is, that position absolute is not working inside overflow: auto. 
regarding the images: I want the last of the 4 examples to look like the first three. there should be no scrollbar, since there should be no content. In my real problem the scrollbar should only apear, if the div has some content that is not absolute.

Comment: removed from the document flow and overflow are two different concept not related to each other. What you want is not possible if you cannot remove position:relative OR remove overflow

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you for that statement. I will investigate if there is any other solution then. Are you able to recommend any documentation or blog posts to read more about this?